# Rails API Strange behaviour on class method load

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid, class-method

The project setup :
I'm running a Rails 6.0.3.4 / Ruby 7.1.2 API linked with Mongoid to MongoDb 4.4.1, and got a controller such as :

```
  module Api
    module V1
      class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Collectionable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Instanceable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Showable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Mutable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Creatable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Updatable
        include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Destroyable

        before_action :set_instance, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

        @@model_module = nil

        def initialize
          super
          @model_name = (@@model_module ? "#{@@model_module}::" : '') + controller_name.classify
          begin
            if @model_name && @model_name != 'Application'
              @model = @model_name.constantize
              @serializer = "#{@model_name}Serializer".constantize
            end
          rescue NameError => e
            Rails.logger.warn "TEST was unable to process model or serializer #{e}"
          end
          @acceptable_params = @regex_params = @regex_default_params = @regex_params = @valid_operators = []
        end
    
        class << self
          def model_module(model_module_name = nil)
            return @@model_module if !model_module_name

            @@model_module = model_module_name
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

then this one who inherits behaviour :

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RunesController < ApplicationController
      model_module 'LanguageConcepts'
      include Concerns::Api::CommonControls
    end
  end
end
```

The concerns are for basic CRUD integration.

I get this very weird and frustrating behaviour :

On start up :

> rails s

When I call a GET method on the index path, I get this :

> undefined method `model_module' for Api::V1::RunesController:Class

though using the console

> rails c

> Api::V1::RunesController.model_module

I get :

> "LanguageConcepts"

Then if I change the method class declaration for :

```
def self.model_module[...]
```

and save, most of the time the problem resolves itself.
Then after a while (random amount of time as I can tell), it gets back to being bugged out and I need to edit again the ApplicationController to reverse it to its previous state.
When it happens again I need to do the same backward, ad nauseam ...

I realy don't get what is going on. An idea anyone ?

Comment: I would consider using a class instance variable instead of a class variable. `@model_module = nil`. They don't have the thread safety and reloading issues of class variables are are not shared between a class and its subclasses (which is nt always desirable).

Comment: Problem with that option is that I would be unable to set it before instanciation. Is there a way to declare on first execution a constant shared with all instances programmaticaly ?

Comment: Thats incorrect. Class instance variables are instance variables that belong to the singleton class. https://www.codegram.com/blog/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: I suggest explaining in words what you are trying to do with model_module. My guess is whatever it's doing isn't properly accounting for/integrated with Rails code loading code (ActiveSupport::Dependencies/zeitwerk etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use class instance variable:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Collectionable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Instanceable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Showable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Mutable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Creatable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Updatable
      include Concerns::Api::Structuralizers::Destroyable

      before_action :set_instance, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

      @model_module = nil

      def initialize
        super
        @model_name = (class.model_module ? "#{class.model_module}::" : '') + controller_name.classify
        begin
          if @model_name && @model_name != 'Application'
            @model = @model_name.constantize
            @serializer = "#{@model_name}Serializer".constantize
          end
        rescue NameError => e
          Rails.logger.warn "TEST was unable to process model or serializer #{e}"
        end
        @acceptable_params = @regex_params = @regex_default_params = @regex_params = @valid_operators = []
      end
  
      class << self
        attr_accessor :model_module
      end
    end
end
```

Declaring an instance variable in the class body declares it in the scope of the singleton class. The result is like a class variable but thread safe and not shared between a class and its sub-classes. Using `attr_accessor :model_module` inside `class << self` declares a class level setter/getter.

Instead of a "macro-method" just go with a setter/getter as its not actually doing anything remarkable:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RunesController < ApplicationController
      self.model_module = 'LanguageConcepts'
      include Concerns::Api::CommonControls
    end
  end
end
```

This code does not require the reader to lookup the definition of `model_module` to see whats going on. We can see right away that we are assigning something.